# SQL query - rewrite in simpler way

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2016

I have the following T-SQL query that does what I need but it contains a lot of duplication. Is there  any way to rewrite it in a more elegant way?

```
SELECT z.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY [action_timestamp] DESC) AS rowNum,
           [new_state] AS [Last_State],
           DATEADD(MONTH, 0, @date) AS [date]
    FROM [dbo].[CR_hist_Data]
    WHERE [action_timestamp_formatted] < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @date)
) z
WHERE z.rowNum = 1
UNION
SELECT z.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY [action_timestamp] DESC) AS rowNum,
           [new_state] AS [Last_State],
           DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @date) AS [date]
    FROM [dbo].[CR_hist_Data]
    WHERE [action_timestamp_formatted] < DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @date)
) z
WHERE z.rowNum = 1
UNION
SELECT z.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY [action_timestamp] DESC) AS rowNum,
           [new_state] AS [Last_State],
           DATEADD(MONTH, -2, @date) AS [date]
    FROM [dbo].[CR_hist_Data]
    WHERE [action_timestamp_formatted] < DATEADD(MONTH, -3, @date)
) z
WHERE z.rowNum = 1;

etc....for 12 times
```

As you can see, I am UNION-ing the same statement with a date shift of one month for 12 times.
Please advise.
Regards.

Comment: Pretty hard to see what you are doing w/o sample data and expected output--but it seems like this could be solved with [`OVER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and it's `ROWS` clause to limit the rows which you want to apply the aggregation or function.

Comment: please add sample records and expected outcome. There might be other ways to solve this but its hard to deduct from this query what you are trying to do

Comment: Ok, let me add some dummy data. thank you for looking into this

Comment: agree with comments. looks like is the first record of each month?

Comment: Last record of each month

Comment: Sorry guys, I revised it: all increments are negative

Comment: Some sample data would really help for this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to test the script, however you can try something like:

```
SELECT z.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id], DATEADD(MONTH,-1 * t.num, @date) ORDER BY [action_timestamp] DESC) AS rowNum,
           [new_state] AS [Last_State],
           DATEADD(MONTH, t.num, @date) AS [date]
    FROM [dbo].[CR_hist_Data]
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)  )  t(num)
    WHERE [action_timestamp_formatted] < DATEADD(MONTH, -1 * t.num, @date)
) z
WHERE z.rowNum = 1
```

Comment: according to OP edit use  negative numbers for `t(num)`

Comment: ohh, he modified the question

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE:

```
SELECT z.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id], MONTH([action_timestamp] ORDER BY [action_timestamp] DESC) AS rowNum,
           [new_state] AS [Last_State],
           CASE WHEN [action_timestamp_formatted] < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date) THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 0, @date)
                WHEN [action_timestamp_formatted] < DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @date) THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @date)
                WHEN [action_timestamp_formatted] < DATEADD(MONTH, 3, @date) THEN DATEADD(MONTH, 2, @date) END AS [date]
    FROM [dbo].[CR_hist_Data]
) z
WHERE z.rowNum = 1
```

Comment: it will not return the same resultset as you have the same partitioning clause, so it will return the same data as the first union

Answer (score 0):

I think using a common table expression might help.

```
with dates(r, currmonth, lastmonth) as
(select 1 r, eomonth(@date) CurrMonth, eomonth(@date,-1) LastMonth
 union all
 select r+1, eomonth(@date,-1*r), eomonth(@date,-1*(r+1)) from dates
 where r < 12)

SELECT z.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id],dates.r ORDER BY [action_timestamp] DESC) AS rowNum,
           [new_state] AS [Last_State],
           dates.currmonth AS [date]
    FROM [dbo].[CR_hist_Data]
    join dates on 1=1
    WHERE [action_timestamp_formatted] < dates.lastmonth
) z
WHERE z.rowNum = 1
```